# How INT database field gets compared to VARCHAR type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure, not writing the complete stored procedure but some of it is:

```
@course int = null,
    SET @query = @query + 'Where course_id='+ cast(@course as varchar)
```

I want to know when I have converted the @course as the VARCHAR type while my `course_id` in the database is of INT type - how the comparison takes place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison between two different types in SQL Server takes place like this:

- First the two type's precedence is compared based on the rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx):

  > the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence
- next the type with lower precedence is casted to the type with higher precedence
- the comparison is then done between the original value of the type with higher precedence and the converted value of the type with lower precedence

For the sake of discussion: an `INT` (precedence 16, high) and a `VARCHAR` (precedence 27, low) would compare by casting the `VARCHAR` to `INT` and then comparing the two.

In your case though there is no conversion occuring, because what happens is that the `@course` value gets appended to the dynamically constructed `@sql`. Needless to say, that is bad. the proper solution is to pass down the `@course` as a parameter to the dymnamic SQL invocation:

```
@course INT = null
...
 SET @query = @query + 'Where course_id= @course';
...
exec sp_executesql @sql, '@course int', @course;
```

This is:

- **faster**: parameterized query instead of hard codded value
- **safer**: lower the risk of SQL injection if code gets refactored and @counter becomes a type tha can carry SQL injection
- **less error-prone**: no risk of NULL value propagating to nullify the entire `@sql`

Comment: your above query will automatically check for the is null for the @course which i am doing explicitly.....like if @course is not null

Comment: sir did u get my question i want to know that will the above query will execute if i write this long query without checking for isNull in dynamic query writing ...like i check for course and branch if @course is not null then only append it same for all parameter i m doing

Comment: I assume that NULL means optional filter, if is NULL then it shouldn't be added to the WHERE. Then branch the construction of the `@sql`: `if @p1 is not null set @sql += 'AND c1=@p1'; if @p2 is not null set @sql += 'AND c2=@p2';` etc. Then pass in *all* parameters to the dynamic SQL: `exec sp_executesql @sql, '@p1 int, @p2 int,...', @p1, @p2,...;`. the dynamic SQL will use the parameters that were added to the `@sql` and ignore those that were not (ie. NULLs).

Comment: this answer misses the point of the question. There is no conversion of different types, he's building up a query as a string but when executed like type is being compared with like type

Answer (score 4):

The rationale to the code you posted is that the data type change needs to occur for SQL Server to allow the string concatenation to happen.  The statement itself is a string, submitted to the optimizer, which sees the comparison as the correct data types - INT to INT.

You can test & confirm for yourself using the following in Management Studio/Toad/etc:

```
DECLARE @course INT
    SET @course = 1234

SELECT 'Where course_id='+ @course
```

This will fail, with an error reading:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Where course_id=' to data type int.

...while this:

```
DECLARE @course INT
    SET @course = 1234

SELECT 'Where course_id='+ CAST(@course AS VARCHAR) AS output
```

...will return:

```
output
---------------------
Where course_id=1234
```

There are other means of approaching [dynamic SQL. I highly recommend reading this article --  The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL -- on the subject](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: so all input data type i should put of varchar type only? i don need to take any int or some other data type for any input parameter for he sql query? is it correct

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: The complication with converting everything to VARCHAR in order to satisfy string concatenation requirements can be really painful to deal with for things like DATETIME/etc.  I recommend the `sp_executesql` approach to dynamic SQL in order to parameterize variables without needing to use explicit data type conversion.

Comment: if i use the approach told by you sp_executesql, i do'tn have to explcitely check for in null property like i am doing in my dynamic query like if @course is not null ...

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you're actually just building another (dynamic) query. So, if you had for example:

```
SET @course = 2
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM Courses'
SET @query = @query + 'Where course_id='+ cast(@course as varchar)
```

the value of @course is converted to characters, appended to the @query and in the end it's:

```
SELECT * FROM Courses Where course_id=2
```

which is perfectly valid sql without the need to convert anything before executing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing comparison (`a = b`) and assignment (`SET @a = b`)

In a comparison between `VARCHAR` and `INT`, the former is always being cast to the latter, so this query will fail:

```
SELECT  1
WHERE   'ab' = 1
```

, since `'ab'` is not castable to `INT`.

In an assignment, the source value (`b`) is always cast to the type of the target (`@a`):

```
DECLARE @av VARCHAR(100)
SET     @av = 1
GO

DECLARE @ai INT
SET     @ai = 'ab'
GO
```

Since an `INT` is always castable to a `VARCHAR`, the first batch will always succeed, unlike the second batch which casts a `VARCHAR` to an `INT`.