# sql server NULL case handing

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query eventhough the value assigned is 0 ,the condition @PARAM='' is returned true.
Can anyone explain  why sql server treating 0 as '' and how to handle this case?

```
declare @param int
set @PARAM=0
select @PARAM
SELECT @PARAM=CASE WHEN @PARAM='' THEN NULL ELSE @PARAM END 
select @PARAM
```

Comment: Why you compare `integer` parameter as a `varchar`??

Comment: @ConradFrix it gives same o/p for you too. clear the first select param and check.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147215/how-int-database-field-gets-compared-to-varchar-type and then try `select convert(int, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server implicitly casts empty string to a 0, so this is why you are getting this result.

It looks as if this question was also brought up here:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=155339

And I quote from this forum robvolk's response the following:

> "Then use an explicit cast as Russell stated. You can't control SQL
>   Server's implicit casting mechanism, you can only work around it."

Answer (score -1):

You cant check a string against an integer value. Change the query as below. Then it start giving an error. "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test' to data type int."

```
**declare @param int
set @PARAM=0
select @PARAM
SELECT @PARAM = CASE WHEN @PARAM='' THEN 'Test' ELSE @PARAM END 
select @PARAM**
```

Comment: The question doesn't do this though. Empty string casts to `0`. So they are doing `SELECT CASE WHEN 0 ='' THEN NULL ELSE 0 END` which doesn't cause a runtime error and goes to the first branch of the `CASE`.