# Why does comparing types in MYSQL not raise an error?

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling, varchar

This:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE comlumn1 = column2;
```

returns results.

This:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 != column2;
```

returned nothing, even though there are cells in the columns that satisfy both requests.

It turned out that column1 was a `varchar` and column2 was an `int`.

My question is why did it not error? Why would one return results and not the other? If the types are different, surely they are always not equal?

**UPDATE**:

The values in `column1` were `varchars` like `1234-34` and `column2` had `ints` like `1234`. This meant it would always match because it would turn the `varchar` `1234-34` into `1234`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147215/how-int-database-field-gets-compared-to-varchar-type

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl Thanks. That's similar, but before the answers I wouldn't have known to look for a question like that. I would argue neither would people searching for this question.

Also my question was _why_ is there no error not _how_ the types get compared. I think it's a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing a string with a number, MySQL tries to convert the string to a number to make the comparison.

If not possible the number result of the string is `0`.

Examples:

```
string value  |   int value  |   comparison result
'abc'         |   1          |   0 = 1 -> false
'1'           |   1          |   1 = 1 -> true
'1abc'        |   1          |   1 = 1 -> true
'abc1'        |   1          |   0 = 1 -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compare a string and an integer in MySQL, MySQL converts the string to a an integer.  The specific rules are described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html).  In your case, these will be compared as floating point numbers.

It is easy to convert the integer to a floating point number.  The string is converted uses implicit conversion -- the first number encountered in the string is converted.  If there is none, then the value is zero.  So, `'12.3abc'` becomes `12.3`; `'abc'` becomes `0`.

This is probably why the comparisons are failing.  However, I would expect the `=` to fail, but the `<>` to succeed.

Comment: Thank you great answer, but @juergen d got there first